# jquery position() in plain javascript

Tags: javascript, jquery, internet-explorer, internet-explorer-5

I have the following line of code:

```
var newLeftPos = $('span#s' + i).position().left - parseInt($('span#s' + i).css('width'), 10);
```

It works great in ie6 and upwards but I also need to get it to work for ie5.5. (Let's not argue about that now - I know - but I have no option)

I'm certain it falls on the .position() while I'm testing on ie5.5 with jquery 1.2

How could I do the same in plain javascript? Could "offsetParent" help me here? Apparently ie5.5 supports that.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: What have you tried so far? Have you examined the source of jquery.js to see how the position() function works?

Comment: I'm _really_ curious who in their right mind is still surfing the internet with IE 5.5, because that means they're probably using Windows 2000, or worse Windows Me.

Comment: QuirksMode has an article on finding element positions http://www.quirksmode.org/js/findpos.html

Comment: Did you have a look at `getBoundingClientRect()` method?

Comment: jQuery will actually allow you to define [cssHooks](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.cssHooks/) to allow it to work properly. So if you do firgure it out, you can use it easily.

Comment: @Andrew: Just FYI: `cssHooks` is only jQuery 1.4.3+ and the OP is using jQuery 1.2.  I have no idea how well jQuery 1.4 will work with IE 5.5.

Comment: Thanks for the replies everyone. I actually found out about the quirksmode find position article, unfortunately there wasn't a working example. The unfortunate fact is also, that I'm not that much of a js expert that I could just look up the jquery source, and get it right from there.(apparently it starts on line 2877(jq1.2)) That's one of the reason why I'm asking the question here. // Unfortunately the later jquery versions don't work on ie5.5, and even when they do load without errors, many times the methods just wouldn't work, as in this case with position(). Oh well, but thanks anyhow.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You are looking for [offsetParent](http://www.quirksmode.org/dom/w3c_cssom.html#offsetParent), offsetLeft and offsetRight.

As you can see in the link, looks like they are supported even by old granny IE5.5.

Check this [text page](http://www.quirksmode.org/dom/tests/elementdimensions.html) to see if they are really supported by your browser first.

Then your function should be something like

```
var span = document.getElementById('s' + i);

var newLeftPos = span.offsetWidth - parseInt(span.style.width);
```

Comment: Hey, thanks a whole lot! That certainly does exactly what I asked for. So simple. It was "offsetLeft" which I used, and that gave the right value. For some reason span.style.width returns null, but I'm sure that's much easier problem to solve. Thanks.

Comment: @Tuomas Ahh yes I forgot offsetLeft! :) Anyway while testing I also noticed the same problem. It return the right value only if the style is inline in the html, but not if it's in a separated css file... don't know why at the moment.

Comment: it's not that simple, if for example `transform: translate(-100px, 0)` is used additionaly, you're lost...as I am right now. You can use this: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52733352/how-to-get-transform-using-javascript but things will get nasty quickly.