# Javascript: Check collision between two divs

Tags: javascript, collision, overlapping

Is there any way to check, if DIV with name for example "character" is overlaping DIV with name "ground" ?

I want to do this with clean Javascript, I know that jQuery is better, but that's what I don't want.
I saw this post: [check collision between certain divs?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9768291/check-collision-between-certain-divs) , but it does not return anything.

Thanks for help.

Comment: Just wanted to point out that *jQuery is better* is not strictly true. It's already been written and tested and has a lot of cool features -- but it's bigger and less customizable than your own project-specific collection of functions would be. Which is "better" is in the eye of the developer.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First, I'd suggest you check out the HTML5 `canvas` element, as by the sounds of it, you want to make a game, and the `canvas` is great for that ;)

But, to answer your question, you could create or get div elements with `document.createElement()` or `getElementById()` respectively, and get their style properties either by getting their JS-set values (`element.style`) or use [getComputedStyle](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/window.getComputedStyle) if you'd prefer to set initial values in CSS.

Make sure that, however you get these CSS properties, they'll need to be parsed into something that JS can digest. For integer-based positions, `parseInt()` usually does the trick.

Next, you do the math. In this case, you'd want to see if the character div's top, plus its height, is greater than the top position of the ground. If it is, it has collided.

To set the style back to the div, you can just set the style property.

Here's an example (copied from [this fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/JSWUQ/1/)):

```js
var character = document.getElementById("character");
var ground    = document.getElementById("ground");

//We could use getComputedStyle to get the style props,
//but I'm lazy
character.style.top = "10px";
character.style.height = "40px";
ground.style.top = "250px";

//For every 33ms (about 30fps)
setInterval(function(){
    
    //Get the height and position of the player
    var charTop    = parseInt(character.style.top),
        charHeight = parseInt(character.style.height);
    
    //and the top of the ground
    var groundTop = parseInt(ground.style.top);
    
    //linear gravity? Why now?
    charTop += 5;
    
    //If the character's bottom is hitting the ground,
    //Stop moving
    if(charTop + charHeight > groundTop) {
        charTop = groundTop - charHeight;    
    }
    
    //Set the character's final position    
    character.style.top = charTop + "px";
},33);
```

```css
#character {
    position: absolute;
    width: 40px;
    height: 40px;
    left: 50px;
    background-color: #F00;
}

#ground {
    position: absolute;
    width: 300px;
    height: 60px;
    left: 0px;
    background-color: #A66;
}
```

```html
<div id="character"></div>
<div id="ground"></div>
```

One more thing: While there are convoluted ways to get element positions when elements use different positioning properties (ex: the player uses `top`/`left` coordinates, where the ground uses `bottom`), it's a lot harder to manage.

Answer (score 0):

The only jQuery that was being used in that linked answer was to get with `width`,`height`, and `position` of the divs, which are somewhat trivial to retrieve using pure JS:

[CSS / JavaScript - How do you get the rendered height of an element?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/526347/css-javascript-how-do-you-get-the-rendered-height-of-an-element#526352)

[jquery position() in plain javascript](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7389421/jquery-position-in-plain-javascript)

[How do I retrieve an HTML element's actual width and height?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/294250/how-do-i-retrieve-an-html-elements-actual-width-and-height)

It's not returning anything because the `.top` `.left` and `height` variables in the `return` statement were relying on jQuery functions that retrieve the information mentioned above.