# How to get transform using Javascript?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, transform

I want to get "transform" data below using Javascript.

```
<svg id="svgHarita" width="5025px" height="2159px" viewBox="0 0 5025 2159" version="1.1" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" xmlns:xlink="http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink" style="transform: scale(3) translate(45.5px, 122px);">
```

- var x // output: scale(3)
- var y // output: 45.5px
- var z // output: 122px

Thanks, 
Regards

Comment: Please visit the [help], take the [tour] to see what and [ask]. Do some research, search for related topics on SO; if you get stuck, post a [mcve] of your attempt, noting input and expected output.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

getAttribute and Regex

```js
var regex = /scale\((\d)\).*?translate\((.*?), (.*?)\)/
console.log(
  document.getElementById("svgHarita").getAttribute("style").match(regex)
);
```

```html
<svg id="svgHarita" width="5025px" height="2159px" viewBox="0 0 5025 2159" version="1.1" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" xmlns:xlink="http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink" style="transform: scale(3) translate(45.5px, 122px);">
```

Answer (score 0):

You can add simply using `style.transform`

```
document.getElementById("svgHarita").style.WebkitTransform = "scale(3) translate(45.5px, 122px)"; 
document.getElementById("svgHarita").style.msTransform = "scale(3) translate(45.5px, 122px)"; 
document.getElementById("svgHarita").style.transform = "scale(3) translate(45.5px, 122px)";
```

Comment: I do not think that is what was asked

Comment: I think, he/she want to transfrom svg using css

Comment: I think he wants to get the values of scale and translates

Comment: Okey it will be

Answer (score 0):

It's using js, will be better using some better regExp, but it does its job

```js
let el = document.querySelector("#svgHarita")
let arr = el.style.transform.replace(/[\(\)translatescale,px ]/gi, " ").replace(/ +/gi, " ").trim().split(" ")
let x = arr[0]
let y = arr[1]
let z = arr[2]
console.log(x, y, z)
```

```html
<svg id="svgHarita" width="5025px" height="2159px" viewBox="0 0 5025 2159" version="1.1" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" xmlns:xlink="http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink" style="transform: scale(3) translate(45.5px, 122px);">
```

Comment: it removes all text then leaves numbers and period, its replaced by " " , then we replace that  "           "   "           " s   p   a    c    e    d  "  text to a "spaced" one, finally we split and get the array using the " " as splitter

Comment: Yes it is indeed simpler to use a well crafted RegEx :) - Also you lost the px